# Компиляция 7-zip c помощью MSYS2

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Подскажите, как компилировать [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) c помощью MSYS2

Comment: Подскажите, а как тогда компилировать, через MS VS?

Comment: Если не трудно, вы не могли более подробнее подсказать, как компилировать с помощью vc++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подробная инструкция по компиляции с помощью MSVC [доступна здесь](http://www.ski-epic.com/2012_compiling_7zip_on_windows_with_visual_studio_10/index.html).

Добавлю вариант с компиляцией через **Cygwin**:

1. Скачиваем [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/): выбираем версию x32. Устанаваливаем, например, в директорию `C:\projects\tools\cygwin`. Из доступных пакетов понадобятся: `make, gcc/g++, wxwidgets`. Соглашаемся с установкой предложенных пакетов.
2. Скачиваем нужную версию 7zip под POSIX-системы: [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/). Распаковываем, например, в директорию `C:\projects\other\7zip\source`.
3. Запускаем Cygwin.bat, переходим в директорию, где распакована библиотека 7zip: `cd /cygdrive/c/projects/other/7zip/source`.
4. В директории с исходниками есть множество makefile для различных платформ, выбираем `makefile.cygwin` и копируем содержимое в файл `makefile.machine`.
5. Выполняем `make -j4` для компиляции цели **all**.
6. Редактируем файл `install.sh` для указания своего пути установки скомпилированных файлов. Находим параметр `DEST_HOME` и изменяем его, например, так: `/cygdrive/c/projects/other/7zip/build`.
7. Выполняем `./install.sh`
8. Теперь в каталоге `/bin` расположен исполняемый файл 7za.exe. Для его запуска копируем следующие библиотеки: cyggcc_s-1.dll, cygstdc++-6.dll, cygwin1.dll, из каталога `cygwin_install_dir/bin`.
9. 7zip готов к использованию